# Memory Leaks in for loop (Objective-C iPhone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, for-loop, memory-leaks

I'm getting quite a few memory leaks with the loop in my `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` method. Just wondering whether anyone can lead me in the right direction as to how to decrease the amount of memory leaks occurring? Perhaps it isn't the best code... any help with other areas would be greatly appreciated.

```
//  SearchViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "VenueDetailViewController.h"
#import "OverlayViewController.h"
#import "TBXML.h"
#import "CoreLocationController.h"

@interface SearchViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, CoreLocationControllerDelegate> {
    VenueDetailViewController *venueDetailView;
    IBOutlet UITableView *tv;
    NSString *navBarTitle;
    NSMutableArray *venues;
    NSMutableArray *primaryCategories;
    NSString *categoryId;

    //Search properties.
    OverlayViewController *overlayView;
    IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
    BOOL letUserSelectRow;

    //Core location properties.
    CoreLocationController *CLController;

    BOOL searching;

    NSMutableData *responseData;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *navBarTitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CoreLocationController *CLController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) VenueDetailViewController *venueDetailView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) OverlayViewController *overlayView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tv; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *venues;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *primaryCategories;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *categoryId;

- (void)doneSearching_Clicked:(id)sender;
- (void)findLocations:(id)sender;
- (void)loadPlacesWithLat:(NSString *)lat andLong:(NSString *)lng;
- (void)findPostcode:(NSString *)postcode;
- (void)showReloadButton;

@end

//  SearchViewController.m

#import "SearchViewController.h"
#import "GenericCell.h"
#import "FSVenue.h"
#import "AsyncImageView.h"
#import "Helper.h"
#import "JSON.h"

@implementation SearchViewController

@synthesize tv;
@synthesize venueDetailView, overlayView;
@synthesize CLController;
@synthesize navBarTitle;
@synthesize venues, primaryCategories;
@synthesize categoryId;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    //Set the title.
    navBarTitle = @"Nearby Places";
    self.title = navBarTitle;

    //Set background and border to clear (to allow for background image to be visible).
    tv.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [tv setSeparatorColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    //Add the search bar.
    tv.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
    searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

    letUserSelectRow = YES;

    venues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    primaryCategories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //Core location init.
    CLController = [[CoreLocationController alloc] init];
    CLController.delegate = self;

    //Add a refresh icon to the top right navigation bar.
    [self showReloadButton];

    if (self.categoryId != nil) {
        [self findLocations:nil];
    }

    searching = NO;

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)showReloadButton {
    UIBarButtonItem *refreshItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                    initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh
                                    target:self
                                    action:@selector(findLocations:)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = refreshItem;
    [refreshItem release];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Nearby Places / Core Location

- (void)findLocations:(id)sender {
    // Display loading overlay view.
    if (!searching) {
        [Helper beginLoading:self.view withTitle:navBarTitle];

        [self doneSearching_Clicked:nil];

        //Calls locationUpdate delegate method.
        [CLController.locMgr startUpdatingLocation];

        searching = YES;
    }
}

- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location {
    NSString *lat;
    NSString *lng;
#if !(TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)
    lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", location.coordinate.latitude];
    lng = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", location.coordinate.longitude];
#else
    lat = @"-37.816016";
    lng = @"144.969717";
#endif

    [self loadPlacesWithLat:lat andLong:lng];
}

- (void)locationError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"locationError: %@", [error description]);
}

- (void)loadPlacesWithLat:(NSString *)lat andLong:(NSString *)lng {
    [CLController.locMgr stopUpdatingLocation];

    responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.foursquare.com/v1/venues.json?geolat=%@&geolong=%@", lat, lng];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)findPostcode:(NSString *)pcode {
    //Webservice URL: http://ws.geonames.org/findNearbyPostalCodes?postalcode=2000&country=AU&style=SHORT&maxRows=1

    NSString *suburb;
    NSString *postcode;
    NSString *lat1;
    NSString *lng1;

    // load and parse an xml string.
    TBXML* tbxml = [[TBXML alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
                                        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ws.geonames.org/findNearbyPostalCodes?postalcode=%@&country=AU&style=SHORT&maxRows=1",
                                         pcode]]];

    // obtain root element.
    TBXMLElement *root = tbxml.rootXMLElement;

    // if root element is valid.
    if (root) {
        // search for the first geonames element within the root elements children.
        TBXMLElement *code = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"code" parentElement:root];

        if (code != nil) {
            // find the lat child element of the code element.
            TBXMLElement *lat = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"lat" parentElement:code];

            if (lat != nil) {
                lat1 = [TBXML textForElement:lat];
            }

            // find the long child element of the code element.
            TBXMLElement *lng = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"lng" parentElement:code];

            if (lng != nil) {
                lng1 = [TBXML textForElement:lng];
            }

            // find the postalcode child element of the code element.
            TBXMLElement *postalcode = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"postalcode" parentElement:code];

            if (postalcode != nil) {
                postcode = [TBXML textForElement:postalcode];
            }

            // find the postalcode child element of the code element.
            TBXMLElement *name = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"name" parentElement:code];

            if (name != nil) {
                suburb = [TBXML textForElement:name];
            }

            NSLog(@"Searching Postcode %@ (%@) ...", postcode, suburb);
            NSLog(@" Lat - %@", lat1);
            NSLog(@" Long - %@", lng1);

            [self loadPlacesWithLat:lat1 andLong:lng1];
        }
    }

    // release resources
    [tbxml release];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark JSON Over HTTP

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"connectin didFailWithError: %@", [error description]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [connection release];

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //[responseData release];

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [responseString JSONValue];
    [responseString release];

    NSArray *venueArray = [[[dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"groups"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKeyPath:@"venues"];

    if ([dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"error"] != nil) {
        [Helper displayAlertMessage:[dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"error"] withTitle:@"Foursquare"];
    }

    for (id result in venueArray) {
        FSVenue *venue = [[FSVenue alloc] init];
        venue.name = [result valueForKeyPath:@"name"];
        venue.venueId = [result valueForKeyPath:@"id"];
        venue.geoLat = [result valueForKeyPath:@"geolat"];
        venue.geoLong = [result valueForKeyPath:@"geolong"];

        NSDictionary *primaryCategoryDict = [result valueForKeyPath:@"primarycategory"];

        FSPrimaryCategory *primaryCategory = [[FSPrimaryCategory alloc] init];
        primaryCategory.iconUrl = [primaryCategoryDict valueForKeyPath:@"iconurl"];
        primaryCategory.iconUrl = [primaryCategory.iconUrl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".png" withString:@"_64.png"];
        primaryCategory.nodeName = [primaryCategoryDict valueForKeyPath:@"nodename"];
        primaryCategory.primaryCategoryId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [primaryCategoryDict valueForKeyPath:@"id"]];

        //Check if categories match the category selected from the FSCategory controllers.
        if (self.categoryId != nil) {
            if ([self.categoryId isEqualToString:primaryCategory.primaryCategoryId]) {
                [venues addObject:venue];
                [venue release];
                [primaryCategories addObject:primaryCategory];
                [primaryCategory release];
            } else {
                [venue release];
                [primaryCategory release];
            }
        } else {
            [venues addObject:venue];
            [venue release];
            [primaryCategories addObject:primaryCategory];
            [primaryCategory release];
        }
    }

    [tv reloadData];

    //Hide loading overlay view.
    [Helper finishLoading:navBarTitle];

    searching = NO;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [venues count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"GenericCell";

    GenericCell *cell = (GenericCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:nil options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                cell = (GenericCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        AsyncImageView *oldImage = (AsyncImageView *)
        [cell.contentView viewWithTag:999];
        [oldImage removeFromSuperview];
    }

    FSPrimaryCategory *primaryCategory = (FSPrimaryCategory *)[primaryCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    FSVenue *venue = (FSVenue *)[venues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    AsyncImageView *asyncImage = [[[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 3, 48, 48)] autorelease];
    asyncImage.tag = 999;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:primaryCategory.iconUrl];
    [asyncImage loadImageFromURL:url];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:asyncImage];

    //The two images are 1x140 vertical gradients that UIKit automatically stretches horizontally to fit the width of the cell.
    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cell_1x140.png"]];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CellSelected_1x140.png"]];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.titleLabel.text = venue.name;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (venueDetailView == nil) {

        venueDetailView = [[VenueDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VenueDetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        FSVenue *venue = (FSVenue *)[venues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        venueDetailView.vid = venue.venueId;

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:venueDetailView animated:YES];
    }

    venueDetailView = nil;
    [venueDetailView release];
}

- (NSIndexPath *)tableView :(UITableView *)theTableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (letUserSelectRow)
        return indexPath;
    else
        return nil;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row % 2) {
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:((float)173 / 255.0f) green:((float)173 / 255.0f) blue:((float)176 / 255.0f) alpha:.60]];
    } else {
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:((float)152 / 255.0f) green:((float)152 / 255.0f) blue:((float)156 / 255.0f) alpha:.60]];
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString *titleHeader;

    if ([venues count] == 0) {
        titleHeader = @"No venues were found.";
    } else {
        titleHeader = @"";
    }

    return titleHeader;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 55;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Search Bar

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)theSearchbar {
    //Add the overlay view.
    if (overlayView == nil)
        overlayView = [[OverlayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OverlayViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    CGFloat yaxis = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat width = self.view.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat height = self.view.frame.size.height;

    //Parameters x = origin on x-axis, y = origin on y-axis.
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, yaxis, width, height);
    overlayView.view.frame = frame;
    overlayView.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    overlayView.view.alpha = 0.5;

    overlayView.searchView = self;

    [tv insertSubview:overlayView.view aboveSubview:self.parentViewController.view];

    letUserSelectRow = NO;
    tv.scrollEnabled = NO;
}

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar {
    searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;
    [searchBar sizeToFit];

    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar {
    searchBar.showsScopeBar = NO;
    [searchBar sizeToFit];

    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:YES];

    [self doneSearching_Clicked:nil];

    return YES;
}

- (void) doneSearching_Clicked:(id)sender {
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];

    letUserSelectRow = YES;
    tv.scrollEnabled = YES;

    [overlayView.view removeFromSuperview];
    [overlayView release];
    overlayView = nil;

    //Reverse geocode postcode entered.
    if (![searchBar.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        [self findPostcode:searchBar.text];
        searchBar.text = @"";
        [tv reloadData];
    }
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar {  
    [self doneSearching_Clicked:nil];
}

- (void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar {
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [tv reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [navBarTitle release];
    [venueDetailView release];
    [CLController release];
    [tv release];
    [venues release];
    [primaryCategories release];
    [categoryId release];
    [responseData release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Hello. I guess you should first add an else statement in case your self.categoryId is not equal to the primaryCategoryId, and then release your venue / primaryCategory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `self.categoryId != nil` and `![self.categoryId isEqualToString:primaryCategory.primaryCategoryId]`, then `primaryCategory` and `venue` are leaked. I'd just factor `[primaryCategory release]` (and the same for `venue`) out of the branches, and put it at the end of the loop.

For future help, you might like XCode's "Build and Analyse" mode, which should statically detect this kind of code flow leak and tell you exactly what allocation is leaked where.

Answer (score 1):

You are leaking the `venue` and `primaryCategory` whenever `self.categoryId` is set but does not match `primaryCategory.primaryCategoryId`.

Your code could certainly be cleaned up:

- Add an `-[FSVenue initWithResult:]` method.
- Add an `-[FSPrimaryCategory initWithDictionary:`] method.
- Decide whether to use a high-resolution icon based on the device.
- The `if` statements at the end of the loop contain duplicated code. Consider doing this instead:

```
for (...) {
    ...

    //Check if categories match the category selected from the FSCategory controllers.
    if (self.categoryId
        && ![self.categoryId isEqualToString:primaryCategory.primaryCategoryId]) {
        [venue release];
        [primaryCategory release];
        continue;
    }

    [venues addObject:venue];
    [venue release];

    [primaryCategories addObject:primaryCategory];
    [primaryCategory release];
}
```

- Consider using `autorelease` whenever you create an object. Then you would not have leaked anything in the first place!

Comment: Autoreleasing is a lazy (and potentially dangerous) solution. Do not consider this point :P I agree with other points.

Comment: Also, I'd like to know how I could best go about implementing your -[FSVenue initWithResult:] and -[FSPrimaryCategory initWithDictionary:] methods to suit my needs. Thanks so much for providing a solution for my if statement. Much appreciated.

Comment: Okay, still getting memory leaks with venue and primaryCategory objects. Err, this sucks.

Comment: Oh this part is optional I guess. There's no problem with the way you do it right now; Jeremy's suggestion is the way to do it in "a perfect world" but there's no obligation :)

Comment: You should release both venues and primaryCategories outside the for loop

Comment: You mean the arrays or the objects?

Comment: Because I use the arrays in my cellForRowAtIndexPath by doing FSPrimaryCategory *primaryCategory = (FSPrimaryCategory *)[primaryCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: Arrays :) Every time you init an object, you have to release it when you don't need it anymore. Objects are handled right.

Comment: If I release my arrays there then how are they going to work in my cellForRowAtIndexPath? I get *** -[__NSArrayM count]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7e61d00 occurring.

Comment: Ah! I you use your arrays in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, you should consider making these arrays properties of your class (UIViewController), init the arrays in the viewDidLoad() method and release them in the dealloc() method.

Comment: I see what you meant. I've now moved them into the viewDidLoad() and I'm deallocating them in my dealloc method.

Comment: Just to let you know. With the above loop it adds the venue and the primaryCategory objects multiple times in the arrays so I get duplicate records in my list.

Comment: Yeah the loop is broken; the initial one was kinda OK (except the missing deallocs)

Comment: Well this loop works fine if I move my arrays from my viewDidLoad() into my method that has the loops. But, I still get memory leaks!

Answer (score 1):

```
venues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
primaryCategories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (id result in venueArray) {
    FSVenue *venue = [[FSVenue alloc] init];
    venue.name = [result valueForKeyPath:@"name"];
    venue.venueId = [result valueForKeyPath:@"id"];
    venue.geoLat = [result valueForKeyPath:@"geolat"];
    venue.geoLong = [result valueForKeyPath:@"geolong"];

    NSDictionary *primaryCategoryDict = [result valueForKeyPath:@"primarycategory"];

    FSPrimaryCategory *primaryCategory = [[FSPrimaryCategory alloc] init];
    primaryCategory.iconUrl = [primaryCategoryDict valueForKeyPath:@"iconurl"];
    primaryCategory.iconUrl = [primaryCategory.iconUrl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".png" withString:@"_64.png"];
    primaryCategory.nodeName = [primaryCategoryDict valueForKeyPath:@"nodename"];
    primaryCategory.primaryCategoryId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [primaryCategoryDict valueForKeyPath:@"id"]];

    //Check if categories match the category selected from the FSCategory controllers.
    if (self.categoryId != nil) {
        if ([self.categoryId isEqualToString:primaryCategory.primaryCategoryId]) {
            [venues addObject:venue];

            [primaryCategories addObject:primaryCategory];
        }
    } else {
        [venues addObject:venue];

        [primaryCategories addObject:primaryCategory];
    }
    [primaryCategory release];
    [venue release];
}
```

You're leaking venue and primaryCategory unless they meet the conditions to be inserted in the arrays. The correct structure of this loop is above.
I take it that the arrays 'venues' and 'primaryCategories' are ivars and you release them in the dealloc method of your class. (or else you're leaking those arrays too.)

Comment: This is correct. I'm releasing them in the dealloc method of my class because they're ivars.

Comment: I've since moved the init of the two arrays to the viewDidLoad() instead of before the for loop.

Comment: Ouch. With your for loop I'm getting: *** -[FSPrimaryCategory iconUrl]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x98f39e0

Answer (score 1):

After the discussion we add in Jeremy's answer, here's a suggestion of code.

In your object's .h file

```
@interface MyObject : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource> {
    NSMutableArray *venues;
    NSMutableArray *primaryCategories;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *venues;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *primaryCategories;
```

In your object's .m file

```
@implementation MyObject

@synthesize venues;
@synthesize primaryCategories;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.venues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.primaryCategories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

- (void)whatEverMethodYouLike {
    // The for loop here (with proper deallocs)
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    FSPrimaryCategory *primaryCategory = (FSPrimaryCategory *)[primaryCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // Et caetera
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [self.venues release];
    [self.primaryCategories release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. This is exactly what I'm doing already. The only difference was my venues and primaryCategories arrays were being initialised before the loop instead of being initialised in the viewDidLoad(). Much appreciate you taking the time to provide the code though.

Comment: One question though, I never use "self" for my ivars. Is this bad practice?

Comment: No it's ok, i'm used to used "self" whenever i define my vars as properties but depends on the context :)

Comment: Okay, great. So - I'm still getting memory leaks with all of the above code suggestions. Any other ideas? I've actually gone back to my original for loop (but without the arrays being initialised in there of course).

Comment: Well ... I guess the whole code would help :P I guess it's all about the for loop and I don't know what suggestions you followed exactly.

Comment: I've edited my original post and added my interface and implementation. That's everything!

Comment: Adding the else statement after the 'if([self.categoryId isEqualToString:primaryCategory.primaryCategoryId])' with releases doesn't help with the leaks?

Comment: It does help a little. I've just re-added that else statement.

Comment: No there isn't! :) Okay, bed time.

Comment: Okay, so if I move my arrays into the viewDidLoad() every time I do a search it keeps adding the same results to the objects and then to arrays so I get duplicate records every time I findLocations. Oh and I'm still getting a whole lot of memory leaks as well.

Comment: I guess you should not add your objects to the array in your else() condition? I can't see why you have IF(CONDITION) { ADD } ELSE { ADD }

Answer (score 0):

you have one leak primaryCategory , because inside the if statement u have another if statement .. so there might have possibilities of memory leak

Comment: Justicepenny: Can you please elaborate? What's wrong with having another if statement inside the if statement and how "might" there be a memory leak because of this? I'm releasing primaryCategory after it gets added to the primaryCategories array though?

Comment: if ([self.categoryId isEqualToString:primaryCategory.primaryCategoryId]) {
            [venues addObject:venue];
            [venue release];

            [primaryCategories addObject:primaryCategory];
            [primaryCategory release];
    }

Comment: put [primaryCategory release]; outside of the if else statement

Comment: Crap. I clicked down instead of up. Sorry!